# 16 bit std_logic_vector to lower 8 bit std_logic-vector in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

Am having an output of 16 bit std_logic_vector from one block.But in the later stage i have to use only lower 8 bit std_logic_vector.it creating synthesis problem...please tell me how to avoid this..

Comment: Could you share some code?  It can help to understand your problem.  But in general, this should not create a synthesis problem.  A syntax problem is more likely.

Comment: actually..we are using half of a bus ...remainig pins are unconnected..thats the problem in real hard ware..am following structural modelling..one blok out(15 downto 0) as a in of next block (7 downto 0) in portmap..so what to do with 15 downto 8

Comment: What synthesis problem are you getting?  Post some code and error message please?

Answer (score 8):

If you have a 16-bit `std_logic_vector` you can access the individual bytes like this:

```
signal largeVariable      : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal lower8bitsVariable : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal upper8bitsVariable : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

(...)

lower8bitsVariable <= largeVariable(7 downto 0);     --Store the lower 8 bits of largeVariable
upper8bitsVariable <= largeVariable(15 downto 8);    --Store the upper 8 bits of largeVariable
```

Comment: we are not interested in 15 downto 8..further processing only on remaining 7 downto 0 only.so synthesis shows ports r un connected..

Comment: The last line is just for completeness. If you don't use the upper 8 bits for anything, synthesis should just show a warning that the upper part of the port is unconnected, and optimize it away. If edited my post a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: You shouldn't avoid it - it's just your synthesizer telling you that it will be optimizing away some ports - it's not critical, and you don't need to avoid it.

Comment: I hav another doubt..I have 2 blocks each with speed of 150mhz and 234.56 MHz..when they combined using structural modelling ..how to acheive atleast 150 Mhz...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - and you should probably open a new question for that.

Comment: I mean output of one block is given as a input to another block...pipelining methodology,then how can achevie minimum frequency of any one of 2 blocks..

Comment: Again, this is a completely different question - so please create a new question for it, and get this one closed.